# Trying to perform integer optimization with unique values in python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to perform solve an optimization problem in python. At this point, I'm already familiar with Scipy, but I didn't manage to use it properly with a constraint of unique integer values.

The example below might better fit mlrose tag.

In a high level, I'm trying to create a Swiss pairing, I have seen a few articles and one of those suggested a "Penalty Matrix" and to minimize the penalty. Here is what I have done:

```py
import mlrose
import numpy as np

# Create Penalty Matrix
x = np.round(np.random.rand(8,8)*50)
z = np.eye(8, dtype=int)*100 + x

print(z)
# fitness problem given a penalty matrix and an order
def pairing_fittness(order, panalty):
  print(order)
  order = np.array(order)
  a = np.bincount(order)
  order = order.reshape(-1, 2)
  PF = 0
  for pair in order:
    print("{}, {}: {}".format(pair[0],pair[1], panalty[pair[0],pair[1]]))
    PF = PF + panalty[pair[0],pair[1]]
  print("Real PF: ",PF)
  print("order penalty: {}".format((np.max(a) - 1) * 1000))
  return (PF + (np.max(a) - 1) * 1000)
```

One of the problems this tries to solve is to create an array with unique values (The same player can not play twice in the same round) this is why the penalty for duplicated values is high (1000)

```py
kwargs = {'panalty': z}

fitness_cust_problem_fun = mlrose.CustomFitness(pairing_fittness, **kwargs)
problem = mlrose.DiscreteOpt(length = 8,
                             fitness_fn = fitness_cust_problem_fun,
                             maximize = False,
                             max_val = 8,
                            )

best_state, best_fitness = mlrose.simulated_annealing(
    problem,
    max_attempts = 300,
     max_iters = 100000,
    random_state = 1)

print(best_state)
print(best_fitness)
```

No matter what I do, with over 6 variables it can not find a unique values array to optimize it. While I can do it in Excel (Solver > Evolutionary).

I'm looking for a better tool (I used scipy.optimize but I'm not sure it works well for integer problems, as I got better results with mlrose) or suggestions on how to improve my optimization problem so it is solvable.

Comment: Mixed Integer Programming can be used to design tournament schedules ([example](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/06/more-tennis-scheduling.html)). There are numerous integer programming solvers and frameworks available for Python.

Comment: Could you clarify what rules your solved matrix has to satisfy?

Comment: the same player (unique integer in the array) can not play twice in the same round. But since this is basically random integer placement, not sure how "learning" can help here