# Generating tournament brackets / Finding subgraphs

Tags: algorithm, tournament

I'm trying to make a bracket generator similar to the Swiss style, but drawing games in batches of 2 rounds unlike Swiss which requires the results of the most recent round to generate the next round of games.

I decided to try using some kind of rating system (Glicko, elo, whatever...) for the seeding - every player starts with the default rating (so initial matches are random), and then matches are drawn such that the sum of squares of rating differences is minimal and after each batch of matches, the ratings are updated with the results. However, I must also prevent 2 players from playing more than once (especially in the same round).

I thought about representing each round as a graph - all of the "possible" matches would be the edges and each vertex would be a player, so the possible matches would be the complete graph of n vertices (then I can set repeat matchups from previous rounds to have a very high "distance" so they never get picked). The problem then becomes finding the right subgraph such that each vertex is connected exactly twice and the sum of squares of distances is minimized.

This sounds a bit similar to the traveling salesman problem but the matches can be completely "disjoint" - if we have:

```
1 vs 2
2 vs 3
3 vs 1

4 vs 5
5 vs 6
6 vs 4
```

when we represent this as a graph, the two groups of 3 are disconnected.

I haven't been able to come up with an efficient algorithm for this, nor find an analogous problem that has been solved.

Comment: While a very interesting problem, it might be better to ask it in [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), as they'll probably be better suited to help you.

Comment: Related: [Trying to perform integer optimization with unique values in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910974/trying-to-perform-integer-optimization-with-unique-values-in-python)

Comment: Also perhaps useful: [github/ Integer Programming Project (SwissChessPairingSystem with gurobipy)](https://github.com/leonardocalizaya/Integer-Programming-Project)

Comment: Important note: a graph with constant degree 2 is necessarily a disjoint union of cycles. So, what you're trying to do when computing the pairings for a round: (1) Group the players by their current score; (2) In each group, add and edge for every pair of players who haven't played eachother yet; (3) Find a [disjoint union of cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cycle_cover) that covers the resulting graph.

Comment: What is the purpose of making this into brackets? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm is perfectly good for picking pairs while minimizing sum of squares and avoiding previous matches. But picking triplets gets you into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching and NP complete territory.

Comment: This is a really fun problem. I'll try to come up with a solution using [networkx.minimum_cycle_basis](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.minimum_cycle_basis.html) in the following days.

Comment: I'd start with a regular Swiss. Plan a round, simulate the results according to the current ratings, tentatively update ratings, and plan the next round.

Comment: re: @btilly , if I understand correctly, this is what Stef has gone for in their answer but it does not account for some of the cases. For instance, the number of players must be even, but you could have an odd number of players by doing this 3-d matching. This blossom method should be fine though - I just hadn't heard of graph matching problems  before and I expected that 2 edges per vertex would not be much harder.

Comment: @flubb It wouldn't seem that much harder, but it all the way goes from polynomial to NP-complete. As for leftovers, half of numbers are not divisible by 2 but 2/3 are not divisible by 3.  So pairs is better for that.  And by giving extra to any edge with someone who missed one earlier, we spread the byes out.

Comment: Yes, minimum-weight maximum marriage is polynomial, but cycle cover is NP-complete. In my answer I find a minimum-weight maximum marriage, then remove its edges, then find a second minimum-weight maximum marriage in the resulting graph. If there are enough edges remaining (that's a reasonable "if" if the number of rounds is small enough compared to the number of players, but a big "if" if the number of rounds is too large), then both marriages are perfect matchings in the original graph, and their union is a cycle cover.

Comment: The cycle cover resulting from the union of the two marriages is not guaranteed to be minimum-weight (at least I don't think so), but it's an approximation, and it should be "fair" in the sense that we first try to find a very good first match for every player, then a good second match for every player, so no player should have two subpar matches.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a Swiss-like tournament pairing algorithm using `networkx.min_weight_matching`.

The logic of the pairing is in methods `tournament.dist`, which defines the "penalty" of pairing together two players who don't have the same number of wins; and `tournament.get_next_round`.

SOS (sum of opponents' numbers of wins) and SOSOS (sum of opponents' sos) are used as tie-breakers.

I did not implement a method to remove players for a round or to add a bye-player in case the number of players is odd.

```py
from networkx import Graph, min_weight_matching

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, nwins=0):
        self.name = name
        self.nwins = 0
        self.sos = 0
        self.sosos = 0

class DoubleSwissTournament:
    def __init__(self, list_of_player_names=()):
        self.n_players = len(list_of_player_names)
        self.player_list = [Player(name) for name in list_of_player_names]
        self.prev_matches = {i: set() for i in range(self.n_players)}
        self.rounds = []
        self.coeffs = {'nwins':100, 'sos':10, 'sosos':1}
    def add_player(self, name, nwins=0):
        self.player_list.append(Player(name,nwins=nwins))
        self.prev_matches[self.n_players] = set()
        self.n_players += 1
    def recompute_sos(self):
        for p,opponents in self.prev_matches.items():
            self.player_list[p].sos = sum(self.player_list[q].nwins for q in opponents)
    def recompute_sosos(self):
        for p,opponents in self.prev_matches.items():
            self.player_list[p].sosos = sum(self.player_list[q].sos for q in opponents)
    def dist(self, p, q):
        x,y = self.player_list[p], self.player_list[q]
        return sum(coeff * (getattr(x,score) - getattr(y,score))**2
                   for score,coeff in self.coeffs.items())
    def gen_next_round(self):
        g = Graph()
        g.add_nodes_from(range(self.n_players))
        g.add_weighted_edges_from(
            (p, q, self.dist(p,q))
            for p,opponents in self.prev_matches.items()
            for q in set(range(p)).difference(opponents)
        )
        m1 = min_weight_matching(g)
        g.remove_edges_from(m1)
        m2 = min_weight_matching(g)
        round = m1.union(m2)
        self.rounds.append(round)
        return round
    def add_results(self, results):
        for p,q, winner in results:
            self.prev_matches[p].add(q)
            self.prev_matches[q].add(p)
            self.player_list[winner].nwins += 1
        self.recompute_sos()
        self.recompute_sosos()
    def get_standings(self):
        players = sorted(self.player_list, key=lambda p:(p.nwins,p.sos,p.sosos), reverse=True)
        ranks = list(range(1,len(players)+1))
        for i in range(1,len(players)):
            if ((players[i].nwins,players[i].sos,players[i].sosos)
             == (players[i-1].nwins,players[i-1].sos,players[i-1].sosos)):
                ranks[i] = ranks[i-1]
        return [(r,p.name,p.nwins,p.sos,p.sosos) for r,p in zip(ranks,players)]
    def str_standings(self):
        l = self.get_standings()
        l = [('','name','wins','sos','sosos')] + l
        maxlen = max(len(name) for _,name,_,_,_ in l)
        return '\n'.join('{:2}. {:{width}}  {:>4} {:>4} {:>4}'.format(*x, width=maxlen) for x in l)

from random import choice

def main():
    player_names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Chen', 'David', 'Elena', 'Fanfan', 'Gregory', 'Han', 'Irma', 'Jan', 'Kim', 'Lili', 'Mehdi', 'Noah', 'Oskar', 'Penelope']
    tournament = DoubleSwissTournament(player_names)
    print('STANDINGS BEFORE ROUND 1')
    print(tournament.str_standings())
    for round_number in (1,2,3):
        print('\nROUND {}: PAIRINGS'.format(round_number))
        round = tournament.gen_next_round()
        print([(tournament.player_list[p].name,tournament.player_list[q].name)
               for p,q in round])
        print('\nROUND {}: RESULTS'.format(round_number))
        results = [(p,q,choice((p,q))) for p,q in round]
        print(['{} {}-{} {}'.format(tournament.player_list[p].name,int(p==w),int(q==w),tournament.player_list[q].name)
               for p,q,w in results])
        tournament.add_results(results)
        print('\nSTANDINGS AFTER ROUND {}'.format(round_number))
        print(tournament.str_standings())
    return tournament

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tournament = main()
```

Output:

```
STANDINGS BEFORE ROUND 1
  . name      wins  sos sosos
 1. Alice        0    0    0
 1. Bob          0    0    0
 1. Chen         0    0    0
 1. David        0    0    0
 1. Elena        0    0    0
 1. Fanfan       0    0    0
 1. Gregory      0    0    0
 1. Han          0    0    0
 1. Irma         0    0    0
 1. Jan          0    0    0
 1. Kim          0    0    0
 1. Lili         0    0    0
 1. Mehdi        0    0    0
 1. Noah         0    0    0
 1. Oskar        0    0    0
 1. Penelope     0    0    0

ROUND 1: PAIRINGS
[('Kim', 'Fanfan'), ('Oskar', 'Bob'), ('Irma', 'Han'), ('Jan', 'Gregory'), ('Kim', 'Elena'), ('Penelope', 'Bob'), ('Mehdi', 'David'), ('Oskar', 'Alice'), ('Noah', 'David'), ('Penelope', 'Alice'), ('Mehdi', 'Chen'), ('Lili', 'Fanfan'), ('Irma', 'Gregory'), ('Noah', 'Chen'), ('Jan', 'Han'), ('Lili', 'Elena')]

ROUND 1: RESULTS
['Kim 0-1 Fanfan', 'Oskar 1-0 Bob', 'Irma 1-0 Han', 'Jan 1-0 Gregory', 'Kim 0-1 Elena', 'Penelope 1-0 Bob', 'Mehdi 1-0 David', 'Oskar 0-1 Alice', 'Noah 1-0 David', 'Penelope 0-1 Alice', 'Mehdi 0-1 Chen', 'Lili 1-0 Fanfan', 'Irma 1-0 Gregory', 'Noah 1-0 Chen', 'Jan 0-1 Han', 'Lili 1-0 Elena']

STANDINGS AFTER ROUND 1
  . name      wins  sos sosos
 1. Alice        2    2    4
 1. Lili         2    2    4
 3. Irma         2    1    6
 3. Noah         2    1    6
 5. Chen         1    3    2
 5. Han          1    3    2
 7. Elena        1    2    4
 7. Fanfan       1    2    4
 7. Oskar        1    2    4
 7. Penelope     1    2    4
11. Jan          1    1    6
11. Mehdi        1    1    6
13. David        0    3    2
13. Gregory      0    3    2
15. Bob          0    2    4
15. Kim          0    2    4

ROUND 2: PAIRINGS
[('Noah', 'Irma'), ('Lili', 'Alice'), ('Penelope', 'Elena'), ('Lili', 'Noah'), ('Gregory', 'Bob'), ('Kim', 'Bob'), ('Elena', 'Mehdi'), ('Penelope', 'Han'), ('Mehdi', 'Jan'), ('Oskar', 'Jan'), ('Han', 'Chen'), ('Kim', 'David'), ('Alice', 'Irma'), ('Gregory', 'David'), ('Oskar', 'Fanfan'), ('Fanfan', 'Chen')]

ROUND 2: RESULTS
['Noah 1-0 Irma', 'Lili 0-1 Alice', 'Penelope 1-0 Elena', 'Lili 1-0 Noah', 'Gregory 1-0 Bob', 'Kim 0-1 Bob', 'Elena 1-0 Mehdi', 'Penelope 0-1 Han', 'Mehdi 1-0 Jan', 'Oskar 0-1 Jan', 'Han 1-0 Chen', 'Kim 0-1 David', 'Alice 0-1 Irma', 'Gregory 0-1 David', 'Oskar 1-0 Fanfan', 'Fanfan 0-1 Chen']

STANDINGS AFTER ROUND 2
  . name      wins  sos sosos
 1. Irma         3   10   37
 2. Alice        3   10   35
 3. Noah         3   10   34
 4. Han          3    9   36
 5. Lili         3    9   34
 6. Chen         2    9   34
 7. Penelope     2    9   31
 8. Jan          2    8   32
 9. Mehdi        2    8   30
10. Elena        2    7   32
11. Oskar        2    7   30
12. David        2    6   32
13. Gregory      1    8   29
14. Fanfan       1    7   31
15. Bob          1    5   30
16. Kim          0    6   25

ROUND 3: PAIRINGS
[('Lili', 'Han'), ('Elena', 'David'), ('Elena', 'Jan'), ('Chen', 'Alice'), ('Noah', 'Alice'), ('Fanfan', 'Bob'), ('Oskar', 'Kim'), ('Han', 'Noah'), ('Gregory', 'Kim'), ('Fanfan', 'Gregory'), ('Penelope', 'Jan'), ('Oskar', 'Mehdi'), ('Penelope', 'Mehdi'), ('Bob', 'David'), ('Irma', 'Lili'), ('Chen', 'Irma')]

ROUND 3: RESULTS
['Lili 0-1 Han', 'Elena 0-1 David', 'Elena 0-1 Jan', 'Chen 0-1 Alice', 'Noah 0-1 Alice', 'Fanfan 0-1 Bob', 'Oskar 1-0 Kim', 'Han 0-1 Noah', 'Gregory 1-0 Kim', 'Fanfan 0-1 Gregory', 'Penelope 0-1 Jan', 'Oskar 1-0 Mehdi', 'Penelope 0-1 Mehdi', 'Bob 0-1 David', 'Irma 0-1 Lili', 'Chen 1-0 Irma']

STANDINGS AFTER ROUND 3
  . name      wins  sos sosos
 1. Alice        5   20  120
 2. Noah         4   23  116
 3. Han          4   20  123
 4. Lili         4   19  119
 5. Jan          4   18  105
 6. Oskar        4   15  103
 7. David        4   14  103
 8. Irma         3   23  116
 9. Chen         3   20  121
10. Mehdi        3   19  104
11. Gregory      3   14  101
12. Penelope     2   20  108
13. Elena        2   17  106
14. Bob          2   14   95
15. Fanfan       1   16   98
16. Kim          0   16   90
```